# Angular 2 - Using 'this' inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, angular, scope

I have a function like so in my class

```
  showMessageSuccess(){

    var that = this;
    this.messageSuccess = true;

    setTimeout(function(){
      that.messageSuccess = false;
    },3000);

  }
```

How can I re-write this so I don't have to store a reference to 'this' in the 'that' var? If I use 'this' inside the setTimeout, the messageSuccess bool doesn't seem to change/get updated.

Comment: I believe this is not a duplicate, the `this` clause in angular is different from normal javascript. (gets converted to _this in the final code)

Answer (score 478, accepted):

You need to use **Arrow function `()=>`  ES6** feature to preserve **`this`** context within **`setTimeout`**.

```
// var that = this;                        // no need of this line
this.messageSuccess = true;

setTimeout(()=>{                           // <<<---using ()=> syntax
    this.messageSuccess = false;
}, 3000);
```

Comment: It always works. There could be some other problem. i'd like you to investigate it or you can ask a relevant question @RomainBruckert

Comment: thats a great answer!! Thanks, solved a big problem. By the way can you please suggest where else do we need to use ()=> in angular 7?

Comment: @sid: That is ES6/ES7 standard. If you use typescript, it is used everywhere.

Comment: ok so everytime i use angular7/typescript, i have to use () => right?

Comment: Does not work in angular/typescript.... still have to store the outer scope in a variable...

Comment: Hi everyone, realy you can't call setTimeout out of any function, so, if you want to call you can put it on ngInit() hook

Comment: Also applies to **Observable** `let observable = new Observable(this.sendSMS_obs);` `sendSMS_obs = (observer) => {setTimeout(()=>{this.nameFormControl.markAsTouched();/*http post request data=>*/observer.next("Booking successful");
            observer.complete();});};`