# Why undefined elements inside ngOnInit method in Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, masonry

I am initializing a library in my ngOnInit method as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.$grid = jQuery('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',//,
  columnWidth: 384,
  gutter: 24
});
......
}
```

then i am calling this method from that instance, inside ngOnInit as well:

```
 // bind event listener
this.$grid.on( 'layoutComplete',function onLayout() {
  console.log(this.$grid);     
} );
```

so it the method finally looks like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.$grid = jQuery('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',//,
  columnWidth: 384,
  gutter: 24
});

 // bind event listener
this.$grid.on( 'layoutComplete',function onLayout() {
  console.log(this.$grid);     
} );

}
```

But I dont understand why the result printed by console.log is undefined if actually is this.$grid who is calling console.log.

I need to use that instance again inside that method to do something like this:

```
// bind event listener
this.$grid.on( 'layoutComplete',function onLayout() {
  this.$grid.masonry('layout');
} );
```

but I can not because this.$grid is undefined inside that method which does no makes sense for me at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Simply use arrow function or `Function.prototype.bind` method to retain `this`

Comment: @yurzui, could you please show me an example how to do that

Comment: `this.$grid.on( 'layoutComplete', () => {`

Comment: @D.B Take a look to my answer, there's an example code of an `arrow` function.

Comment: Thanks @yurzui. It worked. you were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the way you are binding your event.

In your code `this` refers to the execution context of the anonymous function you've passed to the `on` function (e.g. itself).

If you want to preserve the context of `this`, you have to use an `arrow function` like this:

```
this.$grid.on( 'layoutComplete', () => {
    this.$grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

Comment: Right. Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

try call these inside the AfterViewInit callback lifecycle.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.$grid = jQuery('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 384,
  gutter: 24
 });
 this.$grid.on( 'layoutComplete',() => {
  console.log(this.$grid);     
 });
}
```

> ngAfterViewInit(): Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views.
>   Called once after the first ngAfterContentChecked().
>   A component-only hook.

see angular documentation
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: The lifecycle is not the problem. It's a problem of the "context" of `this`. Take a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106125/angular-2-using-this-inside-settimeout

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ you are right. and i will correct my answer.