# Obtaining a value from an object consisting of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

I have an object including only one Array(17). I would like to get from this array specific value, ex for `index = 4 -> 1523181939`.

How can I get it?

[image]

I am getting a console result by running:

```js
this.temp = this.flights['states'];
console.log(this.temp);
console.log(typeof this.temp);
```

My object **`this.flights`** is of the form

```
{time: 1523183848, states: Array(1)}
states: [Array(17)]
time: 1523183848 
__proto__: Object
```

When I call **`this.flights['states']`** I get:

```
[Array(17)]
```

Lastly when calling **`this.flights['states'][0][4]`** I get an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Starting flights object I am getting from Opensky-Network Api:

```
{
    "time": 1523183840,
    "states": [
        [
            "89906e",
            "EVA857  ",
            "Taiwan",
            1523183838,
            1523183839,
            121.2966,
            25.1178,
            716.28,
            false,
            111.38,
            50.06,
            8.78,
            null,
            746.76,
            null,
            false,
            0
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is `this.temp` the object printed in the image you posted?

Comment: your question seems unclear to me. Do you want to `find` a value in Array ? please explain properly.

Comment: `this.flights.states[0][4]` ?!

Comment: I updated the description to show the problem

Comment: `this.flights.states[4]`

Comment: ***Post your complete Object `flights`***!!!! Learn to be more precise in what your problem is. **What you posted is not a valid Javascript datastructure.**

Comment: @connexo error occures: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined

Comment: That means your object does not have a property `states`.

Comment: It seems from your error that `this.flights.states` is not defined (not sure why you're accessing it with bracket notation). What happens when you log `this.flights.states[0]`, hopefully the same error. Are you doing all the checking in the same spot in your code?

Comment: @connexo it has a property states, because it returns expected array.

Comment: @tenor528 this.flights.states is not valid. Should be used this.flights['states'] instead

Comment: Please go read [ask], and provide a [mcve]. All these screenshots and snippets of code get us nowhere, you need to present something that actually makes the problem reproducible.

Comment: What ***exactly*** does your console.log argument look like?

Comment: _"this.flights.states is not valid. Should be used this.flights['states'] instead"_ - mate you're just proving that you don't know the first thing about this to begin with.

Comment: You got to be kidding. `foo.states[0][4]` works fine with the object you have just shown, https://jsfiddle.net/28psgz2L/

Comment: He's probably getting the data asynchronously, but trying to access it synchronously. That concept seems to be hard to grab for some people.

Comment: @TomekM, check my answer now. It is working.

Comment: If connexio's suspicion/guess is correct, and you are getting this data via an async request, then you probably just need to go read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call to learn how to handle this properly.

Comment: @cbroe *Starting flights object I am getting from **Opensky-Network Api**.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working code is below.**

Access your element of array on an object like this `this.temp = this.flights.states[0][4];`

Do it like below:

```js
var flights = {"time":1523183840,"states":[["89906e","EVA857  ","Taiwan",1523183838,1523183839,121.2966,25.1178,716.28,false,111.38,50.06,8.78,null,746.76,null,false,0]]};



this.temp = this.flights.states[0][4];
console.log(this.temp);
console.log(typeof this.temp);
```

Check out now. It is working code now as per your requirement.

Comment: I need to get access to the Array itself. The object is this.flights['states'] and it consists of Array, which is it's value.

Comment: @TomekM post your exact `Array`

Comment: @TomekM, `{time: 1523183848, states: Array(1)}
states: [Array(17)]
time: 1523183848 
__proto__: Object` here: `states: [Array(17)]` array does not look like part of your object but `states: Array(1)`. Please check your response again and share it.

Comment: I am still getting the same error: AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: How you are getting this `flights` array?

Comment: By this.flights.states[0][4]

Comment: In chrome console it works, but not when I run it in code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168495/discussion-between-vicjordan-and-tomek-m).

Comment: @TomekM, come to chat

Comment: thank you for help. The problem was in syntax when calling setTimeout function. Here is the problem description: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106125/angular-2-using-this-inside-settimeout

Answer (score 1):

**Obviously you're getting your flight data *asynchronously*, but your code is trying to access it *before* it is available.**

I have added an example simulating asynchronous data fetching using `window.setTimeout` below. Hope that solves your problem.

```js
let obj = {
  getData() {
    // this will fill your flights objects after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      obj.flights = {"time": 1523183840, "states": [["89906e", "EVA857  ", "Taiwan", 1523183838, 1523183839, 121.2966, 25.1178, 716.28, false, 111.38, 50.06, 8.78, null, 746.76, null, false, 0]]}
    }, 200)
  },
  flights: undefined
}

obj.getData() // will fetch the data and after 200 milliseconds obj.flights will be available

console.log(obj.flights) // but not now!! returns undefined

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(obj.flights.states[0][4])
}, 500)
```

Comment: I share my code, because setTimeout doesnt work.
https://codeshare.io/5wleMj
The error now is : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'states' of undefined

Comment: You refuse to ***understand*** your problem.