# How to call an event after 3 second based on condition in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a div that contains click event, here once I click "click here" label alert should come based on 2 condition, first one if getListData is true and second one if I click the label only after 5 sec of getListData is true. I have tried but its not working properly. Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<div (click)="clickhere()">Click here</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  getListData: boolean = false;
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  clickhere(){
      this.getListData = true;
      console.log(this.getListData);
      setTimeout(function(){
      if(this.getListData == true){
         alert('true'); 
      }
      }, 3000);
  }

}
```

Comment: you must have a new variables (for example flag) and subscribe/wait for the event that makes getListData = true, then have a timeout and set the flag to true, in the clickhere(), check if flag is true then alert

Comment: I think it would be more helpful to know the what you are trying to accomplish as well as what you have done so far. "second one if I click the label only after 5 sec of getListData is true" is a tough explanation to get you on the right direction

Answer (score 0):

'this' context is not available inside the setTimeout function. You can declare it as an arrow function to show the alert.

> clickhere(){
>         this.getListData = true;
>          console.log(this.getListData);
>         setTimeout(()=>{
>           if(this.getListData){
>             alert('true'); 
>           }
>         }, 3000);
>   }

For reference you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41106146/7309449

Comment: Thanks for your  answer ,actually its not working as per second condtion...if I click the label only after 5 sec of getListData is true , I have mentioned in description.